# Using Twython to pull all (of Miley Cyrus') tweets?

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I'm new to Python and Twython, but I'm working on a project where I want to use Twython to analyze all of Miley Cyrus' tweets. Currently there are 7,193, but Twython will only let me take 200 at a time...how can I scrape all of them? Is there there a way to scrape all of them using Twython or do I have to manually scrape the Twitter website? Ideally I would preserve access to all of the tweets' metadata so I could use it in my analysis (rather than just the text of all of the tweets). Suggestions for code?

Comment: Miley Cyrus would be happy!

Comment: Would you also launch a site after retrieving all the tweets, say mileycyrustweets.com?

Comment: What's preventing you from taking those 7193, 200 at a time?

Answer (score 4):

If you [read the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline), you will see that:

> This method can only return up to 3,200 of a user's most recent Tweets.

So there is no way the API can be used to programatically return all historic Tweets.  And, yes, you are limited to requesting 200 at a time.